# Client Server application with gRPC

Tags: java, maven, grpc, grpc-java

For some reason, the project couldn't compile because of a sequence of errors, It's a multi-module maven project utilizing gRPC.

It's a complicated setting, so I've also uploaded a minimalistic and an isolated example project (2 modules with a class file in each), please [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bffna9pk30y8p0h/ClientServer.zip?dl=0) for local testing. I've been working and learning for the last two days on this.

I've tried to make it as simple as possible in spite of all the outdated information out there.

**Run Server**:  `java -jar Server/target/Server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

**Run Client**: Unable to compile/run and connect to server

```
Root POM
    - Client POM
    - Server POM
```

**a)** First the Client can't find the Server POM irrespective of the dependency mentioned in it's POM file. (see screenshot)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[image]

**b)** Once the above error gets fixed, the Client will throw an error while compiling because of some dependencies errors, I'd highly appreciate for getting it to work, I've spent two days struggling with this.

Comment: can you build the jar from command-line and check if it works? it seems like this is just maven problem.

Comment: turns out I've to run maven from the root, I've been running it within the submodule. Please enlighten on this.